# I have a products table. it have fields : id, type, name what is the sql query to find no of products for each type?

Tags: mysql

I have a products table. it have fields : id, type, name
what is the sql query to find no of products for each type?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group by` to group by a field and the `count()` function to count the number of records.

```
select type, count(products) from products group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) from PRODUCTS
GROUP BY type;
```